# Unable to merge data from FRED

Tags: python, dataframe

The following code works using pandas get_data_fred() method.

```
start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2022, 3, 28)

stk_tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "TSLA", "GOOG"]
ccy_tickers = ["DEXJPUS", "DEXUSUK"]
idx_tickers = ["SP500"]  # , 'DJIA', 'VIXCLS']

stk_data = yf.download(stk_tickers, start, end)

ccy_data = web.get_data_fred(ccy_tickers, start, end)

idx_data = web.get_data_fred(idx_tickers, start, end)


x_merged = stk_data['Adj Close'].merge(ccy_data, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
x_data = x_merged.merge(idx_data, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
x_data.head()
```

And produces the following.

[image: Output from code using Pandas get_data_fred()]

I tried using the FredAPI but im getting an error. Ive printed the individual data frames and it appears as though I'm missing a title above the returned values.

```
start = dt.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2022, 3, 28)

stk_tickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT", "TSLA", "GOOG"]
ccy_tickers = ["DEXJPUS", "DEXUSUK"]
idx_tickers = ["SP500"]  # , 'DJIA', 'VIXCLS']

api_key_fred = os.getenv("API_KEY")

fred = fa.Fred(api_key='MY API KEY IS WRITTEN IN PLAIN TEXT HERE - I TRIED USING THE "api_key_fred' above but it wouldnt accept it)

stk_data = yf.download(stk_tickers, start, end)
ccy_data = fred.get_series('DEXJPUS', start, end)
idx_data = fred.get_series('SP500', start, end)

idx_data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['SP500'],idx_data.columns])

ccy_data.head()

#x_merged = stk_data['Adj Close'].merge(ccy_data, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
#x_data = x_merged.merge(idx_data, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
#x_data.head()
```

This is what the dataframe looks like when using Pandas.

[image: Dataframe with title]

And this is what i get when i use the get_data_fred().

[image: Dataframe from get_data_fred()]

Im assuming the issue is the title, see error code below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\mannf\Documents\My Juypter Notebook.ipynb Cell 9 line 2
     16 #idx_data.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['SP500'],idx_data.columns])
     18 ccy_data.head()
---> 20 x_merged = stk_data['Adj Close'].merge(ccy_data, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
     21 x_data = x_merged.merge(idx_data, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
     22 x_data.head()

File c:\Users\mannf\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:10093, in DataFrame.merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
  10074 @Substitution("")
  10075 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=2)
  10076 def merge(
   (...)
  10089     validate: str | None = None,
  10090 ) -> DataFrame:
  10091     from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge
> 10093     return merge(
  10094         self,
  10095         right,
  10096         how=how,
  10097         on=on,
  10098         left_on=left_on,
  10099         right_on=right_on,
  10100         left_index=left_index,
  10101         right_index=right_index,
  10102         sort=sort,
  10103         suffixes=suffixes,
  10104         copy=copy,
  10105         indicator=indicator,
  10106         validate=validate,
  10107     )

File c:\Users\mannf\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:110, in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     93 @Substitution("\nleft : DataFrame or named Series")
     94 @Appender(_merge_doc, indents=0)
     95 def merge(
   (...)
    108     validate: str | None = None,
    109 ) -> DataFrame:
--> 110     op = _MergeOperation(
    111         left,
    112         right,
    113         how=how,
    114         on=on,
    115         left_on=left_on,
    116         right_on=right_on,
    117         left_index=left_index,
    118         right_index=right_index,
    119         sort=sort,
    120         suffixes=suffixes,
    121         indicator=indicator,
    122         validate=validate,
    123     )
    124     return op.get_result(copy=copy)

File c:\Users\mannf\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:645, in _MergeOperation.__init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, indicator, validate)
    628 def __init__(
    629     self,
    630     left: DataFrame | Series,
   (...)
    642     validate: str | None = None,
    643 ) -> None:
    644     _left = _validate_operand(left)
--> 645     _right = _validate_operand(right)
    646     self.left = self.orig_left = _left
    647     self.right = self.orig_right = _right

File c:\Users\mannf\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py:2422, in _validate_operand(obj)
   2420 elif isinstance(obj, ABCSeries):
   2421     if obj.name is None:
-> 2422         raise ValueError("Cannot merge a Series without a name")
   2423     else:
   2424         return obj.to_frame()

ValueError: Cannot merge a Series without a name
```

How do i add this in to the dataframe?

Comment: answered below why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the type then it is:

```
print(type(ccy_data))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

you can convert it to a dataframe:

```
ccy_data = ccy_data.to_frame(name='DEXJPUS')
```

and then merge:

```
x_merged = stk_data['Adj Close'].merge(ccy_data, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(x_merged)
```

Output:

```
                  AAPL        GOOG        MSFT        TSLA  DEXJPUS
2018-01-02   40.776531   53.250000   80.391846   21.368668   112.18
2018-01-03   40.769424   54.124001   80.765968   21.150000   112.28
2018-01-04   40.958801   54.320000   81.476852   20.974667   112.78
2018-01-05   41.425125   55.111500   82.486984   21.105333   113.18
2018-01-08   41.271263   55.347000   82.571182   22.427334   113.08
...                ...         ...         ...         ...      ...
2022-03-21  163.935791  136.478500  294.982880  307.053345   119.15
2022-03-22  167.345734  140.277496  299.814484  331.326660   120.66
2022-03-23  168.723618  138.503494  295.308258  333.036682   121.02
2022-03-24  172.549881  141.311996  299.853943  337.973328   122.08
2022-03-25  173.194214  141.521500  299.439789  336.880005   121.98
```

Comment: Keep in mind that in your Traceback : "\nleft : DataFrame or named Series". In this case, I did the first thing, I converted the series into a dataframe.